# 14.04 Likes to suddenly lose sound

Tags: 14.04

Every sound in Ubuntu likes to stop play after for example switching from youtube to music player or stopping music and try to play again after few seconds. I need to type pulseaudio -k very often.

Comment: Please attach a logfile (look in `/var/log/pulseaudio` or something similar)

Comment: I haven't a pulseaudio folder.

Comment: Then look up some logs like `dmesg`, or just look it up on net where does pulseaudio store its logs

Comment: Is it what we need?

Answer (score 0):

(   0.000|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
(   0.000|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
(   0.000|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
(   0.005|   0.005) D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 4.0
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
(   0.005|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 7fe9f6f1c60920093d89a56d57125273.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is c2.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
(   0.005|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/dominik/.config/pulse.
(   0.006|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-4.0/modules.
(   0.006|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
(   0.006|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
(   0.006|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.